# How to get access token programmatically in Magento 2 Using SOAP API

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v2

I am trying to get Order details using SOAP API in Magento 2.

I used the access token which is provided by Integration in Backend.

Now I want to fetch that access token programmatically. Can any one please help me. Below is the code which I am currently using.

Thanks.

```
 <?php 

$request = new SoapClient('http://192.168.1.49/magento2/index.php/soap/default?wsdl&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1',
            array(
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
                'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array('http'=> array('header' => 'Authorization: Bearer yqtd86y0tm56tfe5dqtqmevqfn4qtld3')
                    )                               
                )
            )
        );
        $response = $request->salesOrderRepositoryV1Get(array('id'=>'000000001'));
        print_r($response);

?>
```

Comment: .Have you found any solution